# Batch map and lookup with expanded variables

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to do [this](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.MapLookup), but my "v" variable is !expanded!. Augh. I've tried flipping things around but I'm not very good with expansion. How could I adjust the map and lookup to work with an expanded variable?

Comment: You haven't provided nearly enough info. Show your existing code. Explain what you want it to do, and describe how it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set map=mon;Monday;tue;Tuesday;wed;Wednesday;thu;Thursday;fri;Friday;sat;Saturday;sun;Sunday
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (q20764599.txt) DO (
 SET "v=%%i"
 CALL :setv
 ECHO ==!v!==
)
ECHO +%v%+

GOTO :EOF

:setv
CALL SET v=%%map:*%v%;=%%
SET v=%v:;=&rem.%
GOTO :eof
```

This should simulate your wanting to work with `!v!`. The file `q20764599.txt` could contain say a single line reading `tue` which gets assigned to `v` and the magic proceeds from there...